# Programming for MySql and MSSql in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, interface, abstract-class

I have a program written in VB.NET that as part of its function requires the use of a number of database classes.

At the moment the classes are programmed specifically to use objects originating from  **System.Data.SqlClient** and classes such as SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameter and SqlDataAdapter are used.

My aim is to use the analogous classes from **Mysql.Data.MySqlClient** (obtained via the Connector/Net download on the MySQL site). These for example would be: MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlParameter and MySqlDataAdapter.

Is there some way in the code that I could maybe specify an abstract version of the classes (something like AbstractSqlCommand, AbstractSqlParameter) and be able to pick the correct implementation between SqlCommand and MySqlCommand based on the use of some other config variable.

```
        Dim command As New AbsSqlCommand(sql, connection)
        For Each p As AbsSqlParameter In param
            command.Parameters.Add(p)
        Next
        Dim timeout As Integer = 3000
        command.CommandTimeout = timeout
        Try
            connection.Open()
        Catch
            Throw New Exception("Connection failed")
        End Try
        Dim Adapter As New AbsSqlDataAdapter(command)
        Adapter.Fill(table)
        Return table
```

So in the case above some kind of global or configuration variable could be ussed to differentiate between whether AbsSqlCommand is actually used as a MySqlCommand or a SqlCommand [MSSQL] without the need for having to recode every instantiation of these objects to suit the particular database platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a broad question that will be best answered by a [full article like this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/t9f29wbk%28es-es,VS.80%29.aspx), but look at

[System.Data.Common Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tahwysy.aspx)

> The classes in System.Data.Common are intended to give developers a
>   way to write ADO.NET code that will work against all .NET Framework
>   data providers.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have two linq to sql instances (there is no constraint on the number of instances and calsses there in), but I have no experince of using linq2sql with MySQL so I dont know how well it works. Id be inclined to set up a test project add a linq2sql setofdatatclesses and try to connect to a MySQL database, see what happens)